# Spring boot property injection to JPA entity definitions

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Is it possible to use spring boot property placeholder notations in JPA entity defitinions ?
For instance following is not working :

```
@Entity
@Table(schema=@Value("schemaname") , name="tablename")
public class InterfaceModel {
```

Is there a way to make this work ?

Comment: What is the exception ? Post the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there isn't. Check [#829](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/829) in the Spring Boot issue tracker for more details.